# Attribute error: DatasetDict' object has no attribute 'to_tf_dataset'

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am working on fine tuning a data for an NLP project using the hugginface library.
Here is the code i am having the challenge with. Has anyone been able to solve this problem?

from transformers import DataCollatorWithPadding

data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer, return_tensors="tf")

```
tf_dataset = testdata.to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["input_ids", "token_type_ids", "attention_mask"],
    label_cols=["labels"],
    batch_size=2,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    shuffle=True
)
```

NB: I have seen suggestions about upgrading to the latest versions, and i have done that but the problem perists.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. In my case I was working with a csv file. I used the following code to load the dataset:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset_training = load_dataset("csv", file)
```

Then the method `to_tf_dataset` returned:

```
Attribute error: DatasetDict' object has no attribute 'to_tf_dataset'
```

To overcome this issue I loaded the content as a pandas Dataframe and then I loaded again using another method:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv") 

from datasets import Dataset     
dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(data)
```

After that, `to_tf_dataset` method worked correctly. I have no explanation for this answer but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `testdata` is of type `DatasetDict` that holds your train split. `testdata['train'].to_tf_Dataset()` however is a `Dataset` type and will work as expected.